# Keycodes ALT + SHIFT + number

Tags: javascript, jquery, keycode

I am trying to use ALT + SHIFT + number. I have tried:

This is using jQueryUI Drag and Drop. I have not included the .sortable code section.

```
var dest = "";

$(".e01").on("keydown", "#activity_contents a", function (e) {
"use strict";
if (e.altKey && ( e.which === 49 )) {
    dest = "tier1";
    $('p.ethel').remove();
    $('#col_1').append('<p class="ethel sr-only">Item moved to Step 1</p>');


} else if (e.altKey && ( e.which === 50 )) {
    dest = "tier2";
    $('p.ethel').remove();
    $('#col_2').append('<p class="ethel sr-only">Item moved to Step 2</p>');

} else if (e.altKey && ( e.which === 51 )) {
    dest = "tier3";
    $('p.ethel').remove();
    $('#col_3').append('<p class="ethel sr-only">Item moved to Step 3</p>');

} else if (e.altKey && ( e.which === 52 )) {
    dest = "tier4";
    $('p.ethel').remove();
    $('#col_4').append('<p class="ethel sr-only">Item moved to Step 4</p>');

} else if (e.altKey && ( e.which === 53 )) {
    dest = "tier5";
    $('p.ethel').remove();
    $('#col_5').append('<p class="ethel sr-only">Item moved to Step 5</p>');

} else if (e.altKey && ( e.which === 54 )) {
    dest = "tier6";
    $('p.ethel').remove();
    $('#col_6').append('<p class="ethel sr-only">Item moved to Step 6</p>');

} else {
    return false;   
}
$("#"+dest).append($(this).parent());
var count = $("#choices li").size();
if (count > 0) {
    $('.ethan').remove();
    focusNow = $("#choices a").first().prepend('<span class="ethan sr-only">focus is on ' + $("#choices a:first").text() + '</span>');

} else {
    focusNow =  $("#check_activity");
}

focusNow.focus();

    if (count === 0) {
    $('.ernie').remove();
    $("#choices").append('<p class="ernie gone sr-only">That was the last ingredient</p>');
}

if (count === 1) {
    $('.ernie').remove();
    $("#choices").append('<p class="ernie sr-only">There is 1 more ingredient to select</p>');

} 
if  (count === 2) {
    $('.ernie').remove();
    $("#choices").append('<p class="ernie sr-only">There are 2 ingredients to select</p>');

}
if  (count === 3) {
    $('.ernie').remove();
    $("#choices").append('<p class="ernie sr-only">There are 3 ingredients to select</p>');

} 
if  (count === 4) {
    $('.ernie').remove();
    $("#choices").append('<p class="ernie sr-only">There are 4 ingredients to select</p>');

} 
if  (count === 5) {
    $('.ernie').remove();
    $("#choices").append('<p class="ernie sr-only">There are 5 ingredients to select</p>');

} 
if  (count === 6) {
    $('.ernie').remove();
    $("#choices").append('<p class="ernie sr-only">There are 6 ingredients to select</p>');

} 
});
```

HTML

#### Drag and Drop Flowchart

Drag and drop the ingredients into the correct order to make a jam sandwich.

```
                 <div id="activity">
                <div id="activity_contents">
                    <div id="columns" class="clearfix">
                        <div id="col_1" class="column">
                            <div class="column_head"> Step One </div>
                            <ul id="tier1" class="connected" role="region" aria-label="droppable area 1">
                            </ul>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="col_2" class="column">
                            <div class="column_head"> Step Two </div>
                            <ul id="tier2" class="connected" role="region" aria-label="droppable area 2">
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div id="col_3" class="column last">
                            <div class="column_head"> Step Three </div>
                            <ul id="tier3" class="connected" role="region" aria-label="droppable area 3">
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                         <div id="col_4" class="column">
                            <div class="column_head"> Step Four </div>
                            <ul id="tier4" class="connected" role="region" aria-label="droppable area 4">
                            </ul>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                         <div id="col_5" class="column">
                            <div class="column_head"> Step Five </div>
                            <ul id="tier5" class="connected" role="region" aria-label="droppable area 5">
                            </ul>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                         <div id="col_6" class="column">
                            <div class="column_head"> Step Six </div>
                            <ul id="tier6" class="connected" role="region" aria-label="droppable area 6">
                            </ul>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="well" class="clearfix" role="region" aria-label="dragable list items">
                     <span class="sr-only">Use alt+1, alt+2 or alt+3 to move the item into Tier 1, Tier 2, or Tier 3</span>
                        <ul id="choices" class="connected">
                            <li id="ch02" class="choice"><a href="#">put jam on bread</a></li>
                            <li id="ch05" class="choice"><a href="#">Get jam</a></li>
                            <li id="ch04" class="choice"><a href="#">Get bread</a></li>
                            <li id="ch06" class="choice"><a href="#">Put bread on plate</a></li>
                            <li id="ch01" class="choice"><a href="#">Place two slices together to make a sandwich</a></li>
                            <li id="ch03" class="choice"><a href="#">Get jammed bread</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="activity_footer" class="clearfix" role="region" aria-label="check and reset buttons">
                    <a href="#" id="check_activity" class="activity_button" title="Check my answers" >Check</a>
                    <a href="#" id="reset_activity" class="activity_button" title="Clear my answers" >Reset</a>

                </div>
                <div id="result" class="result-alert">
                    <div id="result-txt" class="result-message"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Instead of just alt + number I want to use alt + shift + number. Ultimately I'd like to have the spacebar select or grab the div, tab to the drop container and and use enter to drop. But have not worked out how :-)

```
if (e.which === 18 && e.which === 16 && e.which === 49) {
  //DO SOMETHING
}
if (e.altKey && ( e.which === 16 ) && ( e.which === 49 )) {
  //DO SOMETHING
}
if (e.which === 18) && (e.which === 16) && e.which === 49) {
  //DO SOMETHING
}
```

None of them work. Can someone show me how to combine these keys please.

Comment: Please provide a bit more detail on what you are trying to do. Is this Javascript? We'll probably need a bit more context as well.

Comment: I have added more code Sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the shiftKey flag. Similarly to how you use the altKey flag.

```
if (e.altKey && e.shiftKey && ( e.which === 49 )) {
    //DO SOMETHING
}
```

Comment: If the answer worked for you, you may want to mark it as the accepted answer. Also here is some extra readings on javascript key events: http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html Has lots of browser specific information as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Sendkeys method.

```
 Sendkeys.Send("%(FA)");
```

This simulating the key shortcut for Save As. You do these on a multiple level. For a complete list of codes go to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks Campnerd I'll check this out. sendkeys is a .NET framework as far as I can tell, so can't use it. I am using HtML5 and javaSript/jQuery.

Comment: This code does work however only using the alt + number if (e.altKey && ( e.which === 49 )) {

Comment: it is the same concept but now you have a list of every combo you just have to use it in the right languauge.. codes are universal